# Will I be able to enter Malaysia (or any other south-east Asian countries) after being deported from Japan?

Tags: malaysia, asia, deportation

I'm about to get deported from Japan back to Canada. Sad part is, Japan was only the first stop in a large trip around Asia. I'm being deported for a tiny amount of drugs that should never have been in my bag in the first place.

My question is, how will this affect my future travel plans? Singapore is the first stop on our trip and we were wondering if I would even be allowed to enter. Will there be a permanent blemish on my passport that is easy to see (stamp or electronically)? Or does Japan keep this kind of information to themselves?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but... Both Malaysia and Singapore have draconian penalties for drug offences up to and including the death penalty. If you're the sort of person for whom drugs can fall unexpectedly into your luggage then you need to be vigilant in the extreme if you intend to visit south-east Asia.

Comment: Don’t know the answer specifically for Singapore but you have probably rendered yourself inadmissible for most destinations for a very long time